# how to execute voice google search

Tags: c#, voice-recognition

I can't search in google using my voice. I disabled search by default and can only be enabled by saying the word "search". I separated the words and phrases to be searched for to another file so that it wont get mixed with my recognition file and the response file. I placed the path file under the if statement of "search" so that it can only be access when the I speak "search"

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    //user and jarvis texts 
    string[] grammarFile = (File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Friday AI\user.txt.txt"));
    string[] responseFile = (File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Friday AI\jarvis.txt.txt"));


    //speech synthesis
    SpeechSynthesizer speechSynth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

    //speech recognition
    Choices grammarList = new Choices();
    SpeechRecognitionEngine speechRecognition = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

     public Boolean search = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        //initialize grammarfile
        grammarList.Add(grammarFile);
        Grammar grammar = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(grammarList));

        try
        {
            speechRecognition.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
            speechRecognition.LoadGrammar(grammar);
            speechRecognition.SpeechRecognized += rec_SpeechRecognized;
            speechRecognition.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            speechRecognition.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }

    private void rec_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        string result = e.Result.Text;
        int resp = Array.IndexOf(grammarFile, result);

        if (search)
        {
            Process.Start(@"chrome.exe", "--incognito https://www.google.com/search?q=" + result);
            label5.Text = "Enabled";
        }

        if (wake == true)
        {
                                                    if (result.Contains("search"))
                        {
                            search = true;
                            string[] globalsearch = (File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Friday AI\global search words.txt"));
                            grammarList.Add(globalsearch);

                            label5.Text = "Enabled";
                        }
```

Comment: Set break points(or Console.WriteLine())in your code to see where it is failing. Also note in your example searchfile is loaded?, but never used(watch out for silent failures).  Are you ever setting the boolean variable `search` back to false?

Comment: the searchfile is loaded. the boolean "search" is false by default and once it is enabled it will never go back to false.

Comment: Can you establish where the code is failing or methods/events not being called?

Comment: the code didn't have any methods or events error. I renamed the searchFile to globalsearch and added it to the grammarList so that it will detect the words/phrases when I speak. i changed the code under the if statement.